# How to find foreign keys that don't have corresponding indexes?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have installed Oracle database 11g R2 with a customized application. In my environment we are experiencing locking on tables. I want to check if there are  foreign keys in my database without the corresponding indexes. Is there any query or procedure to find un-indexed foreign keys?

Answer (score 7):

Oracle SQL Developer ships with a report to find these unindexed columns.

[image: View > Reports to access this feature]

Here's the SQL behind this report:

```
select a.owner            "Owner",
                                 a.table_name       "Table_Name",
                                 a.constraint_name  "Constraint_Name",
                                 a.columns          "Foreign_Key_Column_1",
                                 b.columns          "Foreign_Key_Column_2",
                                 a.owner             sdev_link_owner,
                                 a.table_name        sdev_link_name,
                                 'TABLE'             sdev_link_type
                            from 
                            ( select a.owner, substr(a.table_name,1,30) table_name, 
                                 substr(a.constraint_name,1,30) constraint_name, 
                                   max(decode(position, 1,     substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position, 2,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position, 3,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position, 4,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position, 5,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position, 6,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position, 7,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position, 8,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position, 9,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position,10,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position,11,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position,12,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position,13,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position,14,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position,15,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(position,16,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) columns
                                from sys.dba_cons_columns a,
                                     sys.dba_constraints b
                               where a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
                                 and a.owner = b.owner
                                 and (:OWNER is null or instr(b.owner, upper(:OWNER))>0)
                                 and b.constraint_type = 'R'
                               group by a.owner, substr(a.table_name,1,30), substr(a.constraint_name,1,30) ) a, 
                            ( select table_owner, 
                                     substr(table_name,1,30) table_name, substr(index_name,1,30) index_name, 
                                   max(decode(column_position, 1,substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position, 2,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position, 3,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position, 4,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position, 5,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position, 6,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position, 7,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position, 8,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position, 9,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position,10,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position,11,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position,12,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position,13,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position,14,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position,15,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) || 
                                   max(decode(column_position,16,', '||substr(column_name,1,30),NULL)) columns
                                from sys.dba_ind_columns 
                               group by table_owner, substr(table_name,1,30), substr(index_name,1,30) ) b
                      where a.owner      = b.table_owner (+)
                        and a.table_name = b.table_name (+)
                        and substr(a.table_name,1,4) != 'BIN$'
                        and substr(a.table_name,1,3) != 'DR$'
                        and b.table_name is null
                        and b.columns (+) like a.columns || '%'
                      order by a.owner, a.table_name, a.constraint_name
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no procedure exist in the database rather we can create one to list out all the un-indexed foreign key constraints. Actually if you google on it you will find plenty of scripts.
Well I have the following query to get the result.

```
SQL> select uc.table_name, uc.constraint_name
from user_constraints uc
where uc.constraint_type='R'
and exists
(select ucc.position, ucc.column_name
from user_cons_columns ucc
where ucc.constraint_name=uc.constraint_name
minus
select uic.column_position as position, uic.column_name
from user_ind_columns uic
where uic.table_name=uc.table_name
); 

TABLE_NAME             CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
DEPARTMENTS            DEPT_MGR_FK
COUNTRIES              COUNTR_REG_FK
TB_COSTS               TB__COST_FK

SQL>
```

(Where constraint_type='R' means we are interested in Referential (Foreign Key)).

Comment: +1.  We have a nightly Oracle Scheduler job on all of our Oracle Databases that emails us the results from such a query in order to find new instances of those pesky unindexed foreign keys.